# XAML: User Control not propagating changes to binding source

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, user-controls, windows-runtime

I am developping an ImagePicker user control for Metro UI. Its principle is simple: it displays an image and when the image is tapped, a file dialog is opened allowing to change the current image. To achieve that, the user control simply exposes an ImageSource property to which the wrapped image binds to.

```
<local:ImagePicker Source="{Binding PictureUri, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

On startup the binding just works fine and displays the picture from the PictureUri property provided by my view model. The issue is, when I tap the image and pick a new one, the new one is displayed but **the binding value is not updated in my view model** despite the TwoWay binding mode. I believe this issue comes from my user control code but I don't get why the value is not propagated up the view model when it is actually propagated to the wrapped image...

So here is the XAML part.

```
<UserControl x:Name="ImagePickerUserControl"
    x:Class="ImageUserControl.ImagePicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid x:Name="ImagePickerRootGrid" Background="Gray">
        <Image Source="{Binding Source, ElementName=ImagePickerUserControl}"/>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

And the code part, sorry for the length but I believe everything is important here.

```
public sealed partial class ImagePicker : UserControl
{
    public ImagePicker()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Hookup event to handle when the control is tapped
        this.Tapped += ImagePicker_Tapped;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImagePicker),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(ImagePicker.OnSourceChanged)));

    public ImageSource Source
    {
        get
        {
            return (ImageSource)this.GetValue(ImagePicker.SourceProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ImagePicker.SourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update Visual State
    }

    private async void ImagePicker_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Pick up a new picture
        FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        var pngFile = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        // If the user picked up a file
        if (pngFile != null)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(await pngFile.OpenReadAsync());

            // Update the source image
            this.Source = bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the issue the just a mistake from my part but I can't get to understand what is happening here. If you wanna try to run the project and have a better view of the code, I uploaded and shared it on SkyDrive: [ImageUserControl](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=6306CB0FD66DCF1A!850&authkey=!AAUOVm9RHmCHtP8)

Thanks for your patience for reading such a long post.

Comment: What happens when you remove the async modifier? A while ago, there was a bug where an [exception wasn't raised using async](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/bea154b0-08b0-4fdc-be31-058d9f5d1c4e). Also, I'm not entirely sure, but you cannot use async to update something on the UI thread.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I wish I could try but of course, the file picker does not provide synchronous methods. I am gonna try with a hard coded string.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I just tried synchronously and everything still behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

The two way binding doesn't work because your dependency property is of type `ImageSource` and your view model property is of type `Uri`. The binding can't convert an `ImageSource` to an `Uri` therefore the value isn't set. You need a property of type `Uri` on your user control to make the two way binding work.

EDIT:

If you only change the dependency property to a different type, the inner image won't display any more if the user selects a file your app wouldn't have access to without the picker. Your app only gets access to such a file by using the returned `StorageFile`, but not using its absolute path. Inside the control you could solve that by having two dependency properties: `ImageSource` like now for displaying the inner image and `Uri` for returning the path. Since you'll be binding to the second one, you'll need to add a callback which will set the `ImageSource` property when the 'Uri' changes from the outside.

Depending on what you want to do with the result outside the user control, this still might not be good enough for you. If you want to access the file there you'd either need to return a `StorageFile` or put the file in [FutureAccessList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx) and return the token.

Comment: This time, the view model receives the change but the inner image does not change but disappears.

Comment: @Ucodia I included some additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output window when you are running the code you will see the following:-

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Error: Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression: Path='PictureUri' DataItem='ImageUserControl.PictureViewModel'; target element is 'ImageUserControl.ImagePicker' (Name='ImagePickerUserControl'); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource').

This is because the property you are binding an ImageSource to a URI. The easiest fix is to change your imagepicker's source to be a uri as follows:-

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace ImageUserControl
{
    public class PictureViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ImageSource pictureUri;

        public ImageSource PictureUri 
        { 
            get
            {
                return this.pictureUri;
            }

            set 
            {
                if (this.pictureUri != value)
                {
                    this.pictureUri = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("PictureUri");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then modify your view model locator as follows:-

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace ImageUserControl
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {}

        public PictureViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return new PictureViewModel
                {                    
                    PictureUri = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-resource:/Files/Assets/eels.jpg"))
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The event then fires as you would expect. If you do require the URI of the image then you will have to add it as an additional property.

(Bonus points for using the Eels album art as your test image).

Comment: I thought about it but the thing I dislike is that I would have to add the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace to my view model. Not such a big deal but I am a bit reluctant to put object with a graphical concept in view models. But I'll definitely consider it more if no other solution comes up. Thanks.